# How to change the date on an exported batch

Tags: database, batches

I have exported a batch but the date in the title is not correct, so I need to change the date on the name of the batch, however I cannot seem to re-open the batch. Please can you help.
Thanks in advance, 
Grace

Answer (score 4):

A financial batch once exported cannot be reopened through UI. But you can reopen/update a batch using a api.

[image]

If you want to change only title of the batch than i would recommend you to change the batch only title using api rather reopening the whole batch.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am quite new with CiviCRM and not very tech savvy so please could you tell me how I can get onto the CiviCRM API page?

Comment: You can navigate to Support >> Developer >> Api Explorer.

Comment: Grace, Were you able to update the Batch?